# Not able to pass URL for webapp testing in appium

Tags: java, android, appium

I am trying to do webapp testing using appium.I am able to launch chrome browser but it showing "data;" instead of passing url (http://google.com) and chrome is getting close it happens twice/thrice and get exception saying SessionNotCreated
Here is my code

```
public class Test_webApp {
                @Test
                public void test() throws MalformedURLException{
                DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
                  cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
                  //cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Android Emulator");
                  cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"Chrome");
                  cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Android Device");
                  cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION,"4.4.2");
                  AndroidDriver <AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver <AndroidElement> (new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
                  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    driver.get("http://google.com");
                      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    System.out.println("Check device google chrome is opened");
                }

    }
```

I have added this but getting same error

```
String exePath = "D:/mobile_testing/eclipse/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe";
                      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);
```

I am getting this exception in eclipse console

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.SerializedMessageSender.sendMessage(SerializedMessageSender.java:24)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.MessageHub.sendMessage(MessageHub.java:44)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.RemoteTestListener.onTestFailure(RemoteTestListener.java:72)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1895)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1879)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:778)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.SerializedMessageSender.sendMessage(SerializedMessageSender.java:24)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.MessageHub.sendMessage(MessageHub.java:44)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.RemoteTestListener.onFinish(RemoteTestListener.java:34)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.fireEvent(TestRunner.java:1246)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.afterRun(TestRunner.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
FAILED: test
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: unknown error: Device 3a23e10 is not online
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64))) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:00:17 -0800'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-N5JTJRI', ip: '192.168.0.114', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:367)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:161)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:170)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:82)
    at Test_webApp.test(Test_webApp.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all change this line

```
String exePath = "D:/mobile_testing/eclipse/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe";
```

to this line

```
String exePath = "D://mobile_testing//eclipse//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe";
```

Because in a string / is recognized as special character so you need to use escape sequences.

Comment: I think your chrome browser is not compatible with your appium server version. Please let me know your chrome version and appium server version.

Comment: I am using chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) in mobile and on desktop.I am using chrome driver 'ChromeDriver 2.28' which supports chrome 55-57.I also feel that  it is issue with chrome driver.Because Earlier same issue I was getting  on desktop .And when I changed my chrome driver (updated) script was running fine.But this time it doesn't work.
Versions : 
appium : earlier 1.4.13.1 yesterday updated to 1.4.16.1
java : 1.8
ChromeDriver 2.28
chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) If I am missing out something please let me knowand provide me an link from where I can download it.Thanks